# if i remove the class name from the code and call the method direcly it will run, but using class shows me an error

Tags: ruby

If i remove the class name from the code and call the method direcly it will run, but using class shows me an error

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'test/unit'

# define in setup 
def setup
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for:firefox
  @driver.navigate.to "#{@base_url}"
  navigate_to_signin.click
end

class LoginValiation < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_login_blank_validation
    setup
    signin_button.click
    wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) 
    expected = @driver.find_element(:xpath, ".//*[@id='login_form']/div[1]").text
    assert_equal("Login and/or password are wrong.", expected)
    teardown
  end


  # Define in page objects
  def signin_button
    @driver.find_element(:name, "submit")
  end
end
```

output

```
 Error:
test_login_blank_validation(LoginValiation):
NoMethodError: undefined method `find_element' for nil:NilClass
C:/Users/Kuntal.Sugandhi/Desktop/rubyproject/ruby practice/test/login_page.rb:23:in `    signin_button'
 test_login_validation.rb:19:in `test_login_blank_validation'
```

On removing the class and run the test directly

output

```
    test_login_validation.rb:19:in `test_login_blank_validation': undefined method `        assert_equal' for main:Object (NoMethodError
```

Comment: `@driver` is an instance variable and is outside of the scope for the class. try moving setup inside your class and you should be good to go. If you need it multiple places modularize the method and include it in the needed classes.

Comment: You might also want to re-look at how you are using the Test-Unit framework. The `setup` and `teardown` methods are automatically called for each test, so calling them manually seems incorrect.